# Why DL4J NLP example not getting the jars using maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, stanford-nlp, dl4j

I am trying to run the program of DL4J examples from the following link:

https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/word2vecsentiment/Word2VecSentimentRNN.java
But while running the code I get the following debug information:

```
10:48:38.934 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libgomp.so.1 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.935 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libgomp.so.1 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.935 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libgfortran.so.3 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.936 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libgfortran.so.3 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.936 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libopenblas.so.0 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.936 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libopenblas.so.0 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.937 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libnd4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.937 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libnd4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.937 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libjnind4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.937 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-x86_64/libjnind4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.938 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libjnind4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.938 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libjnind4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.947 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libgomp.so.1 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.947 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libgomp.so.1 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.947 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libgfortran.so.3 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.948 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libgfortran.so.3 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.950 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libblas.so.3 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.950 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libblas.so.3 in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.953 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libnd4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.953 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/linux-ppc64le/libnd4j.so in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-linux-ppc64le.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.954 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/jnind4j.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.954 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/jnind4j.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.965 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.965 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.966 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libgfortran-3.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.966 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libgfortran-3.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.970 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libgomp-1.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.970 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libgomp-1.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.970 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libnd4j.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.971 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libnd4j.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.974 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libopenblas.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.974 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libopenblas.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.989 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libquadmath-0.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.989 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libquadmath-0.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.990 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libstdc++-6.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.991 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libstdc++-6.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:38.995 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libwinpthread-1.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:38.996 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/windows-x86_64/libwinpthread-1.dll in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-windows-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:39.058 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libiomp5.dylib in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-macosx-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:39.058 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libiomp5.dylib in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-macosx-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:39.068 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libjnind4j.dylib in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-macosx-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:39.069 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libjnind4j.dylib in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-macosx-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
10:48:39.069 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libnd4j.dylib in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-macosx-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
10:48:39.069 [main] DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file org/nd4j/nativeblas/macosx-x86_64/libnd4j.dylib in url jar:file:/home/aims1/.m2/repository/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/0.4.0/nd4j-native-0.4.0-macosx-x86_64.jar!/ with scanner SubTypesScanner
```

I have checked my Maven `.m2` folder, the jars are available there. But why the program fails to access the jars?
How I can resolve this problem? I am using IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: I don't think there is much of community support available for deeplearning4j here on Stackoverflow. Have you tried chatting with them directly on their website using Gitter? That has always worked for me!

Comment: This isn't the first place we look but we *do* try to look at questions. You just might not get an answer right away.

Comment: The Gitter channel is here: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore this. It's ust a warning from the reflections library:
https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

All it's saying is it can't find classfiles for native code (which makes sense)

Comment: Yes my friend. But I have those jars available on the path it is showing.

Comment: Bit confused as to your response. I think you are confused as to what that warning is actually saying. That warning is saying it can't scan the native files IN THE JAR. It's not saying the jar doesn't exist. And again: this makes sense. Class files don't occur in dlls and .so files. I also said you can ignore it. It doesn't actually affect anything in practice. I wrote the code you are using, I know what it does and what the problems are.